# Fetching the first href from a div using dom

Tags: php, dom, curl

I need to fetch the first href value from a div...but it has got two  and I need to the first one only...here is the following piece of html and my coding...

```
 <div class="buttons">
                                    <!-- Clickout -->
                                    <a href="http://test.com"
                                    class="btn--ir--orange js-btn-click js-clickout-track js-clickout-sink js-ga-tracking

                                                gtm-clickout-11
                                        "
                                    rel="nofollow"
                                    target="_blank"
                                    >
                                        <i class="icon-check"></i>Bekijk product
                                    </a>
                                    <!-- Checkout -->
                                        <a class="btn--il--green margin-mobile-top-medium js-checkout-cart-add"
                                           href="#" data-group="Spiegelreflexcamera"

                                        </a>
                                </div>
```

For this am using the following code...

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $tr) {

if($tr->getAttribute('class') == 'buttons')
 {


     foreach($tr->getElementsByTagName('a') as $at)
     {

      $urnt = "http://kieskeurig.nl".$at->getAttribute('href'); 


     }
     echo $urnt ."<br />";

 }
}
```

This returns me the second href value which is #...can anyone please help me with this...could not figure out why its not reading the first href value...

Comment: Because on every iteration of `foreach` var `$urnt` is overwritten

Comment: @u_mulder...thanks...so what should i do here...as I need to fetch the href of each buttons class

Comment: Use array where to store all classes?

Comment: @u_mulder...also when there a single href in a div am getting the result..

Comment: can you please help little more on this...please

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: i need to fetch the first href from each div with class button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
foreach($tr->getElementsByTagName('a') as $at)
{
    $urnt = "http://kieskeurig.nl".$at->getAttribute('href'); 
}
```

on every iteration `$urnt` variable is filled with new value from `$at`.

**Sure**, you get result with one `href` in a div - because there's only one `href` and it's value in `$urnt` is **not overwritten** by following.

If you want to get first element of collection:

the simpliest way will be break `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($tr->getElementsByTagName('a') as $at)
{
    $urnt = "http://kieskeurig.nl".$at->getAttribute('href'); 
    break;   // you break the loop right after the first iteration
}
echo $urnt ."<br />";
```

Another option is using `item` method, **not tested** but it should look like:

```
$urnt = $tr->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
echo "http://kieskeurig.nl" . $urnt;
```